# Nginx ingress controller path rewrite doesn't work

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've installed nginx using [nginx-stable](https://helm.nginx.com/stable) helm chart and configured ingress rules as follows. Though it's working only for root path as follows,

```
/user/login - working
/user/register - working
/foo/user/login - not working
/foo/user/register - not working
```

I've configured rewrite target as mentioned in the document [ingress nginx rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples) but couldn't make it to work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: foosrv-ingress
   annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: true
 spec:
   rules:
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /foo(/|$)(.*)
         backend:
           serviceName: foosrv-service
           servicePort: 5500
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: foosrv-service
           servicePort: 5500
```

Apparently, It doesn't even identify /foo(/|$)(.*) path rule. I don't see any logs in the pod when calls to foo path and ingress return 404 as follows,

```
192.168.65.3 - - [23/May/2020:12:40:30 +0000] "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 1685 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.3 - - [23/May/2020:12:40:34 +0000] "GET /foo/user/login HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are [two nginx ingress controllers](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/#compare-versions) OSS and Plus.You have installed the Plus but you need to install the OSS one [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) because you are using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` in the annotations.

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install my-release ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Edit:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true` should be removed because there is no regex in the path and so it's not necessary.

Comment: I've changed the ingress controller to nginx OSS but It won't resolve the issue and still, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: No, it's not even working without '/foo' if I remove the path: /. Any idea?

Comment: Try by adding a host..referring from here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#regular-expression-support ..it says Full hostnames must be used.

Comment: What would be the host in this case? `- host: localhost` works here?

Comment: Referring from here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#test-your-ingress...it can be anything but you need to modify /etc/hosts of the system from, where you are accessing the url

Comment: I configured `- host: myapp.com` and changed the host file. still, the behaviour is the same.
`
http://myapp.com/user/login - working
http://myapp.com/foo/user/login - not working
`

Comment: I removed the following annotations and its started to work. Any idea what was the issue?
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: true

Comment: Can you just remove the use-regex and keep everything else and see if that works?Also enable debug logging https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/#debug-logging

Comment: It works only if I removed all those 3 annotations.